# Object is greyed out, can't edit the color of a material

Tags: materials

I need help with Blender, this model is of a car and I wanted to change the color of the tires. The material is greyed out so I can't change its properties, just wanted to give it a new color.

[image]
[image]

I've tried other solutions, I tried to click on the blue icon to see the Restriction Toggles but it doesn't appear. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: In your first screenshot, I can't see the settings for the Wheels collection.  If the collection is unavailable say because display visibility is off, then you can't access its members.  Please check the settings for it.

Comment: Thank you, already solved it, and yeah it was about visibility, I think I got it working after toggling it on "Shading".